# NIntegrate vs quadGK in Julia

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to understand the numerical integration routine by using as a benchmark the function

```
f[x_] := -x^2 + x^4
```

used to define the following function

```
g[z_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[-f[x]], {x, z, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

As $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = \infty$

I was checking how the computation is performed as the argument of $g$ approaches $0$.

Trying

```
g[10*^-32]
```

I get the warning

```
NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive        bisections in x near {x} = {1.64072643374912601558232961177989984273356228783177323546417714519*10^-29}. NIntegrate obtained 71.8065640502810565832993434204331739193329356186861158845012728424`66. and 2.36220417967229179569077470511748314210153999062657561896751085287`66. for the integral and error estimates.
```

and a result of

```
71.80656405028106
```

For smaller arguments I get

```
g[10*^-100]
217.5365551442017
```

and an error estimate of

```
44.1017
```

I checked this against Julia and its standard integration package QuadGK

```
julia> j = quadgk(h,10^-100,1)
(230.9516545085585, 3.0963683972298146e-6)
```

no sweat, much smaller error.

In Python with Scipy.integrate I obtain similar results, but the maximum number of subdivision has to be increased, and I set it to 500.

Setting

```
MaxRecursion -> 500
```

makes the calculation run for x10 more than Julia, and I still get some error (probably fully acceptable)

```
228.6490713869369
```

What should I improve in my handling of similar divergent integrals in Mathematica (assuming that Julia's claim are realistic..)?

Thanks

Comment: Mentioned in a comment to the answer, but `10*^-100 != 10^-100` (you want the latter)

Comment: @b3m2a1, noted thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the warning, I would try increasing either the `MaxRecursion` or `WorkingPrecision`. Increasing the `WorkingPrecision` only seems to help marginally, so I went with `MaxRecursion -> 20`.

```
f[x_] := -x^2 + x^4
g[z_] := NIntegrate[
           1/Sqrt[-f[x]], 
           {x, z, 1}, 
           MaxRecursion -> 20, 
           WorkingPrecision -> 16
         ]
g[10^-100]
```

> 230.9516564798752

It does still give a warning, but the result seems to be correct to quite a few decimal places. We can verify this by performing the integration with infinite precision first:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[-f[x]], {x, 10^-100, 1}]
```

> `Log[10000000000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000] + 3 Sqrt[11111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   111111111111111111111111111111111]`

and

```
N[%, 16]
```

> 230.9516564799645

Also, in case you didn't already know, if you ever put a number like 10.^-100 that has a decimal, unless you explicitly tell Mathematica otherwise, it will assume that it is a machine precision number. If there is no decimal in the number (like in your numbers), it will assume it is exact and has infinite precision.

Comment: well I certainly did not know. I was inputting g[10*^-100] and was getting $\approx 228.6$. Using g[10*^-100] gets better, thanks a lot

Comment: @Smerdjakov Oh, that's another thing: `10*^-100` means `10*10^-100` which is actually just `10^-99`. If you want to use that notation, I would use `1*^-100`.